# Why can INDEX(...,COUNTA(...),..) find the last value of one array, but not another?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm learning basic `=ARRAYFORMULA` usage for a finance spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12cAGuUBzIo0LPbmtqWJZNFgjt94f1ybGoj6x2g0c2Y0/edit?usp=sharing

First, I used `=GOOGLEFINANCE` at B1 to pull up stock prices for a given date range in Column C

`=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"price",DATE(2020,1,1),DATE(2020,5,30),"DAILY")`

Then, I used simple arithmetic to multiply by number of shares at D2 and dragged the formulas down to get a nice column of values

`=C2*20`

Then, I used `INDEX` and `COUNTA` to pull out the last value of Column D at F3 === Great!

`=INDEX(AAPL!D2:D,COUNTA(AAPL!D2:D),1)`

Next, I turned my arithmetic formula into an ARRAYFORMULA at G2 === Cool!

`=ARRAYFORMULA(C2:C103*20)`

Of course, the problem with that ARRAYFORMULA is that I would have to manually change the array name in G2 every time the date range updated.

That is, instead of C2:C103, I would need to change the reference to C2:104 to get the columns to match `===` Rookie mistake!!!!!

So, I got smart with an ARRAYFORMULA containing a `IF(ISBLANK(),...,...)` at J2

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",C2:C*20))`

Column J stays fully populated with the correct values for any date range === !!!!!!!

But now the `=INDEX(AAPL!J2:J,COUNTA(AAPL!J2:J),1)` at L3 can't find the last value in Column J

Whaaat???

I've tried everything I can think of

It works if I use `=INDEX(AAPL!J2:J104,COUNTA(AAPL!J2:J104),1)` but that would defeat the purpose, since the reference J:J104 is going to change as the dates change

WHY???

Answer (score 0):

I get the same results in both cells `"L3"` and `"L5"` when using:

> `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),,C2:C*20))`

Check that you are not returning a blank string (`""`) in your `IF` like: `"=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",C2:C*20))"` doing so will fill the cells up to the last row in the sheet with empty strings, thus when you use `COUNTA(AAPL!J2:J),1)` you get a lot more cells than you would expect, these extra cells are the ones you filled with blank strings in the array formula.

On the contrary when you limit the `=INDEX(AAPL!J2:J104,COUNTA(AAPL!J2:J104),1)` to cells with numbers only it doesn't mix strings and numbers in the calculation and you are naturally get the expected results.